# A batch script that copies directories from one location to another

Tags: testing, batch-file, synchronization

I am trying to write a batch script where I have hard coded a source path and a target path. I have also made a list of the Software I wish to copy. For example SET list=python perl. I want to know how can I determine whether I already have the latest version of the software. Could I extract that information through environment variables? Thanks in advance for the help.

Edit: My apologies. Yes this is on the Windows OS. Prior to asking this question, I have use the command "set" to see if there is any e-vars that are set automatically that contain the software version, but none of them seem to contain that kind of information. Also, I am using robocopy.

ROBOCOPY %SOURCE_PATH% %TARGET_PATH% /E /Z /COPYALL /SECFIX /R:10 /W:1

Comment: possible duplicate of [batch/bat to copy folder and content at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062503/batch-bat-to-copy-folder-and-content-at-once)

Answer (score 0):

How many pieces of software do you have in this list? Each one will have a different way of checking the version - for example; with python you could check the version simply by looking for the directory in your C drive - however that is very unrobust and I would do something like the following:

```
> getVer.py ( echo import sys & echo print^(sys.version^) )
for /F %%a in ('getVer.py') do set pyver=%%a
del getVer.py
echo %pyver%
```

That is how I've had to do it as, for some reason, [this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2005-September/041111.html) doesn't work for me (even though I have Python installed).

My method is only good if you're happy to assume that Python *IS* installed, otherwise you will end up with your script bringing up a dialogue asking what software to open the `.py` file with.

**EDIT:** I have learned different ways to check if your programs exist by asking a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151126/how-to-suppress-open-with-window/21151561?noredirect=1#21151561).