# How to suppress 'Open with' window

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

When running a file which has an unknown extension (lets say `test.nope`) from the command line or a batch file - using `test.nope`, `call test.nope` or `start test.nope` - you are presented with a window asking you to `"Choose the program you want to use to open this file"` (in Windows 7, presumably in most Windows OS's).

**Is it possible to suppress this window?**

My initial thought was to check if the extension exists in the `%PATHEXT%` variable before attempting to open the file. However, this does not contain *all* known file extensions. For example, though the `.py` extension is not in my `%PATHEXT%` variable, Python scripts are still opened correctly.

Comment: What do you want it to do instead of asking you what program to use?  If you know the correct program, why aren't you calling that directly? (`python test.py` rather than `start test.py`)

Comment: Perhaps just a change in errorlevel or something - also that won't always work - though I have python installed and .py files will open using python, I can't use the `python` command, and it's therefore not the best check if the program can be called or not. Still, you may not know what the correct program is to call the file. For example, if you had a list of programs of different types to run. I'm not looking for a workaround in any case, it's merely to do with curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File types are registered in `HKCR\` ([full documentation available from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144104%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).  You can find out if a type is registered by checking for the existence of the key.  In a batch file, you could use the `reg` command to do so.

```
reg query HKCR\.txt || echo This will never print
reg query HKCR\.foobartxt || echo Could not find foobartxt
```

That being said, file types can be defined and named without having a default handler.  Further, those which have default handlers may not have command lines - the file may be launched via DDE or COM.

Comment: @rockstartprogrammer, because I am lazy and they are easy to test.

Comment: @rockstartprogrammer You could alternatively just call the reg query, redirected to null, then check the errorlevel.

Comment: Note that the command is `||` not `|`.  `||` executes only if the previous command set an errorlevel.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to a direct registry query (as suggested by @Mitch) is to use the command line utility [`assoc`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770920%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

```
assoc .nope
```

If there is no application registered for the file extension it produces

```
C:\>assoc .nope
File association not found for extension .nope
```

If an association is found (for instance, for the `.docx` extension), it produces

```
C:\>assoc .docx
.docx=Word.Document.12
```

You might also find [`ftype`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771394%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) useful. It returns the command line for the file type returned by `assoc` (I have Office installed in a non-default location, as you can see):

```
C:\>ftype Word.Document.12
Word.Document.12="D:\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE" /n /dde
```