# Batch file to copy folder to multiple network destinations

Tags: file, batch-file

I have been able to copy files from 1 location to another using the batch file.
However I need to copy the complete folder from one server to multiple servers.

Example;

Local machine name :

LOCAL

Destination machines :

Network1

Network2

folder that i need to copy 
Local\d:\Hello

The whole folder hello and its contents to be copied

to

Network1\c
Network2\c

So the folders thats created should be like (with all the file within)

Network1\c:\Hello

Network2\c:\Hello

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might want to use xcopy. See below;

[batch/bat to copy folder and content at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062503/batch-bat-to-copy-folder-and-content-at-once)

You should end up with a script like this;

```
xcopy d:\Hello \\Network1\c$\ /E
xcopy d:\Hello \\Network2\c$\ /E
```